# Alternative for DWORD in Objective C

Tags: iphone, wav

I am trying opening a audio file (.wav) and retrieve the raw data. I got the below code from the [link](http://www.cpp-home.com/tutorials/333_1.htm). When I am trying to implement the code `DWORD` is not supported in Objective c.

How can I implement this?

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("sound.wav","rb");
if (fp)
{
    BYTE id[4]; //four bytes to hold 'RIFF'
    DWORD size; //32 bit value to hold file size

    fread(id,sizeof(BYTE),4,fp); //read in first four bytes
    if (!strcmp(id,"RIFF"))
    { //we had 'RIFF' let's continue
        fread(size,sizeof(DWORD),1,fp);
        //read in 32bit size value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use any 32-bit unsigned integer value for DWORD, e.g. `uint32_t`.

```
#include <stdint.h>
typedef uint32_t DWORD;
...
```

Comment: @Warrior: I don't know what more detail can be given. Just stick that `typedef` to the start of the file and the code shall compile.

Comment: Thanks, i was totally confused.Sorry for it.

Comment: @Kenny TM:Please give your views to my previous questions,I trying to implement FFT to a wav file.I struggling badly for 4 days.Please help me out.

Comment: @Kenny TM:i have used the below line

   fread(format_length, sizeof(DWORD),1,audioView);

it shows the exception "passing argument 1 of 'fread' makes pointer from integer without a cast".How to solve this exception.

Comment: @Warrior: `fread(&format_length, sizeof(DWORD),1,audioView);`. Have you learned C before? If not, do so.

Comment: @Kenny TM:(!strcmp(id,"RIFF"))-->shows a warning "pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'strcmp' differ in signedness".

Comment: @Warrior: Better use `id[0] == 'R' && id[1] == 'I' && id[2] == 'F' && id[3] == 'F'` instead since `id` is not a string (`char*`).